# Android SQLite display åäö

Tags: android, database, sqlite, encoding

I have a problem displaying the swedish characters "åäö", read from my database, in my android application.

I have created the database using the sqlite3 command-prompt shell and the characters display correctly there. Also "åäö" which are not read from the database display correctly in the application.

I have searched everywhere and I can't think of a solution. I've tryed different encodings on my database text but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you using a webwiev to display the text, if so - it might well be the encoding of the webview that is the root of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not mention whether you are using javaScript/PhoneGap or Java to communicate with Sqlite in Android. // Yes, I know PhoneGap is using Java too.

If you are using pure Java, you better check out the following link as there have been some updates to how Java handles utf-8 encoding. Effected versions are:  JDK7, Open JDK 6, JDK 6 update 1, JDK5.0u17, and 1.4.2_19. As far as I understand, the Java version in Android follows the new regime.

Reference: http://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/the_overhaul_of_java_utf

You mention that you have tried different encodings for the database, however you do not mention whether or not you have done this through Android or from cmd/gui on your desktop.

Anyhow, I will give you some pointers. You probably know all of this already, but I’ll include it anyway.

**HTML**

As Tapirboy mentioned in his comment, make sure you have set the character encoding for whatever view you are using. For HTML5 you can do that like this:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

**CSS**

You should also make sure that you’ve got, and are using, an utf-8 compatible font in Android. The default DroidSans.ttf is capable of drawing utf-8 characters for all western languages.

In CSS the font-family should be set to “Droid Sans” **not** “droidsans”.

**SQLITE**

Check character encoding in sqlite:

```
PRAGMA encoding;
```

Setting character encoding in sqlite:

```
PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-8";
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
</script>
```

As you, I’m developing Android applications in other languages than English. In my case it’s Norwegian and Thai.

I have set the character encoding to utf-8 for Sqlite, webview and javaScript, using PhoneGap 1.1.0 and jQuery 1.6.4, and have no problems displaying Norwegian and Thai characters in Android Emulator.

Hälsning från en norrbagge